# Choose unique value for column in postgres from a sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to be able to specify a dynamic unique value for a column in a table which is in a well defined interval and the values are reused upon deletion for the next insert.

I know this is partially doable either by a sequence and/or nextval, however (if I'm not mistaken) this does not satisfy the requirement that if I delete a row from the table on the next insert the first available value from the interval is returned, and it is also doable by the backend language that manipulates the table, however that feels overengineering.

An example:

```sql
name | id
-----+---
AAA  | 0
BBB  | 1

insert into mtable(name) values ('CCC') returning id; # id will be 2

name | id
-----+---
AAA  | 0
BBB  | 1
CCC  | 2

delete from mtable where name='BBB';

name | id
-----+---
AAA  | 0
CCC  | 2

insert into mtable(name) values ('DDD') returning id; # id will be 1

name | id
-----+---
AAA  | 0
DDD  | 1
CCC  | 2
```

This needs to be in postgres. Is there anyone who can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query to get such a value.

```sql
select min(id + 1)
  from my_table t1
 where not exists (
        select 1
          from my_table t2
         where t2.id = t1.id + 1
    )
```

You can use it in a trigger something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_my_new_id()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    select min(id + 1)
      into new.id
      from my_table t1
    where not exists (
            select 1
              from my_table t2
             where t2.id = t1.id + 1
        )
END;
$$


CREATE TRIGGER my_new_id
BEFORE INSERT
ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE generate_my_new_id();
```

Comment: I would add that an advisory lock must be performed to prevent id conflicts, which would lead to any such solution to be not scalable.

Comment: @JonathanJacobson, I don't believe any reasonably scalable solution exists for the task as stated.

Comment: Perhaps some centralized id generator would be more efficient, but I agree - this is a requirement that kills scalability.

Comment: This is just for a very sparsely used inhouse solution, so scalability is not relevant at the moment, so thank you! (said the optimistic developer)